# Are the following logos the same?

Tags: logo, copyright, legal, trademark

I designed this logo for a company, the logo has 4 curved corners (arrows) which represent the different dimensions that particular company works in and the gap between these arrows shows how open the company is to new ideas and technologies.

The logo on the left is simple and the right one has a little bit of shadow. So my question is, can they use both by trademarking the left one, or do they have to get them both trademarked? Also, does this changes the concept of the logo?
[image]

Comment: You'd have to ask you IP lawyer but I believe you can submit them both as variations of one logo.

Comment: For me they are the same. Any changes in outline, shadow, different colors doesn't mean its a different logo.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of perspective and my general understanding, the logos are the same. I *think* the identity of the logo lies more in the *features design* than color or depth. And I do not think the shadow changes the concept at all. To be on a safer side though, submitting the logo for trademarking in **black, white and grey** usually covers all the colors (*and I think the shadow too in that case, as it's a result of color-tone difference.*) Unless your client is very keen to a specific brand color scheme and they attach a special importance to it, in that case they can submit the colored logo. In both cases I *think* logo 2 is covered.

> *PS: This answer is not a substitute for professional legal advice, a professional trademark lawyer is bound to advise you/your client on that.*

This article on [Trademark, Copyright and Logos](https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2010/08/12/trademark-copyright-and-logos/) and this on [Color and Intellectual Property](http://www.intellectualpropertymagazine.com/trademark/50-shades-of-black-white-and-grey-scale-102382.htm) might be a good read for you/your client